# Bananian or Banananian

Tags: demonyms

Why are people coming from Canada called *Canadian* but Panama *Panamanian*? If someone comes from Banana Republic, should that be Bananian or Banananian?

Comment: Banana Republic is not a country...so you can't call them with either of those terms.

Comment: @MaulikV I think I have seen people using *Niker* to refer to Nike wearers. So I believe it's valid to coin a term based on a certain brand name. It's not a demonym but works in a very similar way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of endings used in English [demonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym). There may or may not be a good reason why one ending is used over another. Where there is a reason, it is likely historical or has to do with the influence of the language spoken by the people to which the demonym refers.

Should the Banana Republic ever become a country, the residents of the country will either proclaim what their demonym should be, or it will emerge naturally as whatever term becomes popular.

Comment: I suggest *Upscalians*.